# How can I submit data and search by PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Although selenium can complete my task,I still want to ask that how can I submit data and search by PyQt5.
For example,I want to submit the data to this website('http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/search') and search it.

[image]

In PyQt4,the codes are:

[image]

But I want to know how to achieve this demand in PyQt5.Thanks for your answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyQt5 for versions >= 5.6 Qt WebEngine should be used and in that case the task should be done through javascript:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
    view.loadFinished.connect(loop.quit)
    url = QtCore.QUrl("http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/search")
    view.load(url)
    view.show()
    loop.exec_()
    view.page().runJavaScript(''' document.querySelector("#search_term").value = '.' ''')
    view.page().runJavaScript(''' document.querySelector("#page_size option:checked").text = '100' ''')
    view.page().runJavaScript(''' document.querySelector("#search").click() ''')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You answer helps me a lot.Thank you.And I have another question I want to ask,can PyQt5 simulate dragging something,like dragging verification bar?

Comment: @SJ2050 what is `verification bar`?

Comment: Like the scroll bar,and I want to know how to use PyQt5 to simulate dragging it.

Comment: @SJ2050 use js with QTimer: `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: view.page().runJavaScript('''window.scrollTo(0, 2500);'''))`

Comment: Thank you again for your patient reply.I want to simulate this action showed in the link. https://img-blog.csdnimg.cn/20181219235701410.gif

Comment: @SJ2050 If you realize that is not a problem of PyQt but of js so I recommend you to review that technology